# Starting byobu with a config file, but getting all the byobu niceties, too?

Tags: 10.04, server, screen, byobu

When one starts `byobu` by saying:

```
byobu -c myconfig
```

unfortunately the whole session looks like a bare bone `screen` session. How can I get the full-fledged `byobu` interface with the status bar and "tabs" for the windows in the session, while at the same time starting `byobu` with a custom configuration file?

Please note: this is not about configuring what's in `$HOME/.byobu` because the contents of that are independent from what I want to achieve - which is special purpose (thus the extra configuration file).

Edit: the only "crutch" I've found so far is to interactively enter the screen command:

```
:source /full/path/to/myconfig
```

... in order to "source" (similar to how it's done in Bash and other shells) the configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, there's a couple of ways you can do this...

1. You can put your customizations in `~/.byoburc`, which is sourced last
2. You can set an environment variable, `BYOBU_WINDOWS=/path/to/a/config`, and then run byobu. Many people use this to start different byobu sessions with different windows open at launch. For more information here, see the `WINDOWS` section of the manpage at: http://manpg.es/byobu.1

Comment: Whoa, an answer from the developer himself. Cool. Thanks for the concise advice.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Hi trying to resolve a copy paste issue in byobu, i am not able to copy and paste text using my mouse, anything i can do to enable that?